# saving a dictionary of lists as a pickle reads the lists back as strings

Tags: python, list, pickle

I have a dictionary that looks like this for example:
`obj = {'a':['d','f','g'], 'x':['y','z','w']}`

I save it to a pickle file using:

```py
with open(str(file_path), 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(obj, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

and read it back with:

```py
with open(str(file_path), 'rb') as f:
    return pickle.load(f)
```

but now the lists are strings that looks like lists:
`{'a':"['d','f','g']", 'x':"['y','z','w']"}`

Is there a way of reading it back straight as a list?

Note: I can convert it back from strings to lists with ast.literal_eval(list) but it's super slow.

Im using python 3.8, windows 10

Comment: what is **obj** ??

Comment: not reproducible on `windows 10` and `python3.8`, the loaded output is `dict` for me, can you please mention the OS and python version are you using?

Comment: I ran your code on my linux system. Seems to work fine. I get a list directly on load. Note : I assumed your `obj` to be the `dict` you provided in your question

Comment: what version of python are you using?  I can't reproduce this on macos python 3.7.6

Comment: checked on python 3.8 working fine

Comment: yes i too have checked with python 3.8.2 and its working fine.